# Is there a way to pin query result in 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio'

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I was looking for a way to pin query result in 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio' similar to how we can do in Oracle SQL Developer. I googled about it but it didn't help. Anyone knows how this can be achieved

Comment: Cah you explain what `pin query result` does in oracle ? I dont know oracle that good so I have no idea what you are looking for

Comment: The fact that you cannot pin the results in SSMS as you are able to in Oracle SQL Developer (A superior IDE) is silly.  Oracle just builds a smart IDE while Microsoft lags so far behind in the features it provides.  In fact it sucks so bad they rely on 3rd party tools like RedGate to pick up the slack.  Oracle comes with SQL History and good SQL formatting whereas Microsoft cannot even include these features in their main products.  If you want to keep the results for viewing you have to copy it out into Excel or some other tool.  Just build the option to Pin the result set Microsoft.  Easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not for query results, but if you are trying to compare result sets in SQL visually, you are doing it the wrong anyway; visual comparisons are far too prone to error. You should be using the [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) keyword to compare results. Load your data from query 1 into a temp table or table variable and do the same for the second query. Below is an example; feel free to populate the tables and see the results for yourself.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (val int)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (val int)

select * FROM @Table1
EXCEPT
select * FROM @Table2

select * FROM @Table2
EXCEPT
select * FROM @Table1
```